# jquery $(window).scroll bottom and make div visible not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i try to display a div when i scroll to bottom of my page and hide it when its not on the bottom.
The alert message work when at the bottom page but setting css visible or trying with fadeIn or out not work. I need little help to see what i did wrong.

Also on IE 9 the div **"#loadSection"** its hidden but i still able to put my cursor on it and click when other browser work correctly.

here my code.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {       
    if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() > $(document).height()){
        $("#loadSection").fadeTo(0,0).css('visibility','visible');
        alert("bottom");
    }else{
        $("#loadSection").fadeTo(0,0).css('visibility','hidden');
    }

});
```

Comment: `.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )` - you are setting opacity to 0 in both cases. I think you should set it to 1 on the if

Comment: oh my mistake thx for noticing that small error

Comment: but still working for IE9 only seem firefox and chrome doesn't care at all

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/aLz7u/

Comment: its kind of weird now working on chrome and firefox but IE seem to toggle it. It show for instant and disapear.

Comment: ok i found the probleme css has a negative margin have to remove from the div to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the fadeIn/Out happens with every bit of scroll and it's causing the div to flash. Here's a CSS animated option:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
    if ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $(document).height()){
        $("#loadSection").addClass('visible');
    }else{
        $("#loadSection").removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/Eh53d/

Answer (score 1):

The visibility property allows an element to remain on the page and take up space. To solve your issue in IE where you're still able to mouse over it, use the display property instead.

To your main issue, try the following:

```
var loadsection = $("#loadSection");
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    if ( loadsection.is(':hidden') ) loadsection.fadeIn();
}else{
    if ( loadsection.is(':visible') ) loadsection.fadeOut();
}
```

fadeIn and fadeOut will utilize the display property, which will completely remove the element when it's not visible. Also, you're fading to zero opacity in both of your fadeTo calls, so even if though visibility is being set, the element is still completely transparent.